# Белый лист для Таск Менеджера

Tags: java, android, android-broadcastreceiver

Здравствуйте.
В некоторых приложениях существуют кнопки, которые отправляют тупых юзеров на нужную страницу в настройках конкретного приложения (см. фото). 
[image: скриншот окна настроек]

Возникает следующий вопрос: как можно отправить человека на страницу настроек белого листа Таск Менеджера (конкретно на моем устройстве меня: Диспетчер батареи -> Защищенные приложения) или есть ли другой способ решить описанную ниже проблему?

---

**Немного подробнее:**
При разработке приложения под Андроид возникла необходимость создания ресивера (`Receiver`) для отслеживания состояния телефона на предмет вызова (если проще, то требуется вывести уведомление о пропущенном вызове). Проблема заключается в следующем: на устройстве с Android 4.4 все работает прекрасно, но на Android 6.0 уведомления не приходят, если приложение было закрыто. 
Ресивер объявляется непосредственно в манифесте:

```
<application>
....
<receiver android:name=".CallReceiver"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
</application>
```